# Group By Alias name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following T-SQL query:

```
select 
    count(CaseId),
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day,CreateDate,LastActivityDate)) AS DiffDate
from 
    VW_Case_Analysis
where 
    CaseStatus = 'C' 
    and LastActivityDate between '2013-4-1 00:00:00.000' and '2013-4-30 23:59:59.000'
Group By 
    DiffDate
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Invalid column name 'DiffDate'.

The idea behind this query is that I want to get number of cases solved (closed) within how many days.

Example:

Days

1 = 3 cases

2 = 50 cases

3 = 20 cases

how can I achieve this?

Comment: It would help if you gave us the table structure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to used the whole expression in the `GROUP BY` clause or just wrap the whole statement in a subquery an do the grouping on the outer statement.

The reason why you can't use `ALIAS` on the `GROUP BY` clause that is created on the same level of the `SELECT` statement is because the `GROUP BY` is executed before the `SELECT` clause in which the `ALIAS` is created.

This is the SQL Order of Operation:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Try this query,

```
SELECT  COUNT(CaseId),
        DiffDate
FROM
        (
            select  CaseId,
                    DATEDIFF(day,CreateDate,LastActivityDate) AS DiffDate
            from    VW_Case_Analysis
            where   CaseStatus = 'C' and 
                    LastActivityDate between '2013-4-1 00:00:00.000' and '2013-4-30 23:59:59.000'
        ) sub
Group By DiffDate
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use alias in the group by clause.

Either use a derived table or in your case simple remove the 2nd SELECT.

```
select 
    count(CaseId),
    DATEDIFF(day,CreateDate,LastActivityDate) AS DiffDate
from 
    VW_Case_Analysis
where 
    CaseStatus = 'C' 
    and LastActivityDate between '2013-4-1 00:00:00.000' and '2013-4-30 23:59:59.000'
Group By 
    DATEDIFF(day,CreateDate,LastActivityDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this get you the same results?

```
select  Count(CaseId),
                    DATEDIFF(day,CreateDate,LastActivityDate) AS DiffDate
            from    VW_Case_Analysis
            where   CaseStatus = 'C' and 
                    LastActivityDate between '2013-4-1 00:00:00.000' and '2013-4-30 23:59:59.000'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,CreateDate,LastActivityDate)
```

I am a novice at SQL so maybe I am not grasping it correctly. I saw the comment above mine with the exact syntax but I didn't know if it was right...

Comment: Hi Dan, the SQL you are providing seems to be the same as @Ahmed's. So if it's a question it should not be posted as answer, if it's thought as answer there is no need for a duplicate answer. Maybe you could remove it?

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. I am not able to delete my original comment for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

this is a easy example of Implementation Discussion

```
select selectResualt.num ,count(selectResualt.num) as count  
from (select src_num As num from mytable  UNION ALL select dis_num As num from mytable) as selectResualt
group by selectResualt.num
order by count(selectResualt.num) DESC;>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to create an alias and use it in the `GROUP BY` clause, like so:

```
select 
    count(CaseId),
    DiffDate
from 
    VW_Case_Analysis
cross apply
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day,CreateDate,LastActivityDate) AS DiffDate) Alias
where 
    CaseStatus = 'C' 
    and LastActivityDate between '2013-4-1 00:00:00.000' and '2013-4-30 23:59:59.000'
Group By 
    DiffDate
```